# Access own defined variable from wp-config-php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to define my own variable in wp-config with below code:

```
/* Add any custom values between this line and the "stop editing" line. */

define( 'MY_VARIABLE', 'MY_VALUE' );

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */
/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    define( 'ABSPATH', __DIR__ . '/' );
}
```

I then try to echo the variables like this in a php file in my theme:

```
echo MY_VARIABLE;
echo ABSPATH;
```

Which gives the following output:

```
MY_VARIABLE     (wrong, expected MY_VALUE)
path/to/.....   (expected)
```

Why does it echo the variable name instead of the variable value? But for ABSPATH it works as it should?

Comment: Follow this Answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109886/how-to-create-custom-variables-in-the-wp-config

Comment: Can't see a reason why this shouldn't work. Check if you really spelt the constant name the same in both places. (My guess would be you haven't, but that any "undefined constant" message gets swallowed by WP's default error suppression.)

Comment: @CBroe, I think it should work too but it doesn't. I copied the variable so it is 100% the same.

Comment: @JahidHasan, that is exactly what I did

Comment: Have you enabled WP debug mode and checked if that has anything to say?

Comment: @CBroe, yes it doesn't say anything. The variable echo, it just echo the variable name and not the value